# How to HTML help file trigger action in C# desktop app?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

We have

- a desktop application programmed in C#
- help files in HTML (created with Sphinx)

The help is stored locally on the user's computer, not in the web.

What we would like to have: The user clicks a button in the help file (i.e., in the browser) and then an example script is opened in the application GUI.

In other words, we would like to trigger an action in C# from HTML or javascript.

What is the typical approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WebView controller in your c# desktop application to display HTML pages in you application.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview